# Trying to parse Tailwind .css file and encountering Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, tailwind-css

I'm completely new to Tailwind, React, and Webpack. I've been trying to get them to work together, but I'm having trouble parsing the main CSS file that has the Tailwind directives.

On execution of my script, I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./static/index.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

I've tried finagling with css-loader, postcss-loader, etc. to no avail.

*"App.js"*

```
import React from "react"

function App() {
    return <div className="bg-slate-900 h-screen">Hello, Tailwind!</div>
}

export default App
```

*"index.js"*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from "./js/App"
import "./index.css"

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

*"webpack.config.js"*

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './static/index.js',  // path to our input file
  output: {
    filename: 'index-bundle.js',  // output bundle file name
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './static'),  // path to our Django static directory
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './static'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: { presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './static'),
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            postcssOptions: {
              plugins: ["postcss-preset-env",],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      },
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    static: 'dist',
    watchContentBase: true,
  },
};
```

Comment: I was able to resolve the error. My initial error was due to .resolve() pointing to the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure of the answer but I think that you could either read through the set up process and see if you missed something or you could just re do it :)
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app